# Modifying a specific field in a Adobe editable PDF using PDFStamper(Append mode) is doubling file size

Tags: pdf, itext, xfa, pdfstamper, xdp-pdf

As per requirement, I have an editable PDF (created from XDP and XML using Adobe) and I want to edit a specific binding field using itext5.
Was able to achieve this using pdfstamper in append mode. But it is doubling the PDF file size. Which seems to be incorrect. eg 5MB --> 9MB, 2MB --> 4MB

Could anyone suggest why this is occurring? Is anything missing in the below code?

CODE:

```
public static byte[] writeFormFieldValue(byte[] uploadedBytes, String fieldName, String Value)
        throws Exception {
    if (uploadedBytes == null) {
        //throw new CertificateCustomException("Inavalid input parameres to parse certificate pdf");
    }
    // ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();\
    byte[] outBytes = null;
    String waterMarkedPDFName = "watermarkedPDF_" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        FileOutputStream bos = new FileOutputStream(waterMarkedPDFName);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(uploadedBytes);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, bos,  '\0',false);
        stamper.getAcroFields().setField(fieldName, Value);
        stamper.close();
        outBytes = WatermarkUtil.getBytesFromFile(new File(waterMarkedPDFName));
        
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            File deleteFile = new File(waterMarkedPDFName);
            if (deleteFile.exists())
                deleteFile.delete();
        } catch (Exception se) {
        }
    }

    return outBytes;
    // return bos.toByteArray();

}
```

Comment: First of all, XFA forms in PDF should be avoided, they are a technology that has been deprecated for more than six years. If you need to support certain xfa forms nonetheless (in particular government bodies are recognizing this only very slowly), please share an example PDF with which we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Try calling "stamper.getReader().removeUnusedObjects()" or "reader.removeUnusedObjects()" to see whether some stuff can be cleaned up. (And stop using xfa as MKL mentioned)